break out of while loop if a certain time passes or any key is pressed (record keypress)
I need a piece of code that waits for a user input OR an elapsed time. If a user presses any key, it records the key pressed and uses that as a variable in the next function before breaking the while loop. If 3 seconds have elapsed and they have not pressed anything, I need it to activate a different function and then break out of the while loop.
Within the context of my program, I need something like:
import time
import date.time
import tkinter as tk

def bind_keypress(func):
    root.bind("<KeyPress>", func)

def function_a():
    print("not important")
    # etc.

def function_b():
    if entry_label.get() in ([a list of keys]):
        print("whatever")
    elif entry_label.get() in ([another list of keys]):
        print("okay")
    else:
        print("nope")
    # etc.

start_countdown = time.time()

while True:
    wait_length = time.time() - start_countdown
    if wait_length >= 3:
        function_a()
        break
    elif [any key is pressed]:
        bind_keypress(function_b)
        break

I have tried to simplify here. I realize that the stuff in my functions could just go directly into the while loop, but that is not what I need. Assume I need the code structured roughly the way it is. I am looking for a solution to the "elif [any key is pressed]" part.
Windows 10, Python 3.1.1
EDIT to reopen:
I have been through the similar questions cited (e.g., here and here). These do not solve my problem. I already know how to detect keypresses (including specific keys), and I know how to wait for a keypress. I specifically need something that waits up to three seconds for a user input and then continues down one of two paths accordingly (path_a if they do not respond fast enough and path_b if they give an input in time).
Once a given path is followed, a new round should begin, so I need to be able to exit out of the input/timeout loop and continue in the same GUI. Root.quit and root.update both kill the program, even if I try to use some sort of nested root.mainloop.

You'll need to handle asynchronous events to achieve the behavior you're describing.
Tkinter has a main loop that is designed for handling events, but it won't work well with Python's while loop if you're trying to handle both simultaneously in a blocking manner.
You can use Tkinter's event loop and its after method to manage the timeout functionality.
import tkinter as tk

def function_a():
    print("function a: time is up!")
    root.quit() 

def function_b(event):
    print(f"function b: key pressed - {event.char}")
    root.quit() 


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200') 


entry_label = tk.Entry(root)
entry_label.pack()
entry_label.focus_set() 

root.bind("<KeyPress>", function_b)
root.after(3000, function_a)

root.mainloop()


thanks for the reply. This seems to work if you can kill the program after a user input or 3 seconds, but I cannot figure out how to get the program to continue running (i.e., not use root.quit()). Atm, this solution in my code does function_a (if an entry is made) followed by function_b, and then continues the game. I need to to do either a or b. Do you know how to make this work?

Here is the best version I have so far (if you want the added context). The trouble occurs at the function defined on line 391: https://drive.google.com/file/d/115mNvds5LOe7-IPep9r1puT87Re7lVPV/view?usp=sharing
